# Incompatible library version puma_http11.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am running `rake db:create` in my ruby on rails project it's giving me error `LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.so`

Here is full error

```
tps@tps-H81M-S1:~/sites/my_app$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-    2.3.1/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.so
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `require'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/puma-  3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma.rb:14:in `require'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma.rb:14:in `<top   (required)>'
/home/tps/sites/my_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tps/sites/my_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this somehow ? I got the same issue - moved Puma into the development section within Gem file - but now on calling rake I get the same issue with other gems ...

Comment: @GeorgKeferböck I changed my ruby-version to which is mention in gemfile, and problem is solved.

Answer (score 6):

Try this(version 3.6.0):

> gem uninstall puma

and

> bundle

or try this

> gem pristine --all

or for specific gem

> gem pristine puma

Comment: or `gem pristine --all`